# Update remote database table with local table using dblink postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, insert-update, dblink

How to update remote table records, from a local temporary table, such like this:

Local Database: There is a table such as localFruit(id, name, color)

Remote Database:there is a table fruits(id, name, color)

I need to update remote field fruits.color with tempFruit.color WHERE fruits.id >20

How to do using dblink?

Comment: use pgAdmin GUI to connect to remote db

Comment: Thanks, but i need to do this with an sql function.